# How to inject facade in servlet on jboss 4.2.3GA?

Tags: servlets, jboss, dependency-injection, ejb

I've got EJB 3.1 app running succesfully on JBoss 7.1
My task is to get it running also on JBoss 4.2 with EJB3 plugin.
App runs OK there except one thing:
In web servlet, I'm using

```
@EJB
private ExchangeRateTableEntityBeanFacade exchangeRateTableEntityBeanFacade;
```

to inject my facade and call method findAll(); to select all rows in related table.

As I've learnt, this is not possible on JBoss 4.2 and I am getting NPE at the moment.
Any ideas how to inject, look up this one?

Comment: I faced the same problem a time ago, after some research I found out that injection doesn't work. The solution was to lookup the ejb reference manually.

Comment: yes, I was able to solve it eventually. Define local interface for my bean, check it via jmx console and then look it up